# How to fix "Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null"?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, cdi, codi, view-scope

I am using JSF 2.1.7 with Primefaces 3.2, CDI and Apache MyFaces CODI for access to @ViewScoped.

Everything has been working absolutely fine but when I pass a bean through to another page via a ui:param and then attempt to use that bean specifically with a p:ajax request, I get the message, "Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null"

```
<ui:include src="page.xhtml">
   <ui:param name="bean" value="#{formBean}" />
</ui:include>
```

Then on page.xhtml I attempt to do this.

```
<p:gmap zoom="15" type="HYBRID" model="#{bean.simpleModel}">
   <p:ajax event="markerDrag" listener="#{bean.onMarkerDrag}" />
</p:gmap>
```

The first call to bean.simpleModel resolves properly.  The ajax call to bean.onMarkerDrag does not.

My declaration of formBean is @Named("formBean"), @ViewScoped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. In my case I used a

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" icon="ui-icon-pencil" actionListener="#{bean.edit}" />
```

inside a template included via `<ui:include>` and got the same error message.

Interestingly the following alternatives did work:

```
actionListener="#{bean.edit()}"
action="#{bean.edit}"
action="#{bean.edit()}"
```

Maybe you should try

```
<p:ajax event="markerDrag" listener="#{bean.onMarkerDrag()}" />
```

i.e. adding parentheses to your method expression.

Answer (score 0):

@ViewScoped is tricky with CDI, it is not fully compatible.  Consider trying with @SessionScoped.

If it works then try with @ViewAccessScoped (since you use Codi). That scope basically adapts ViewScope for CDI usage.

Still problems or already using that? Then try @SessionScope and report back what happened.

Comment: ViewScoped and ViewAccessScoped are not the same. Only the word 'View' is the same, but the behaviour of both scopes are completely different. With CODI you can use both with CDI.

Comment: Yes sorry I remembered it incorrectly. I misread docs about the provided adapter in codi for viewscope

Comment: There really is not a (compatible) ViewScoped implementation in CDI. That is JSF specific and mixing CDI/JSF annotations in this way will just not work.

Comment: @DarrellTeague I use the adapter from Codi in production, it works very well for me.

Comment: This does not look like a scoping problem, but rather a bug in the evaluation of the listener attribute of <p:ajax> in the context of a <ui:include>

Answer (score 0):

That can't work, because it's against the rules of @ViewScoped